# Is there a way to determine if a postgres function depends on a user-defined type?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, functions

I am writing a Ruby script to handle functions and user-defined types in Postgres. I want to make sure, that before a function is created in the database, if it uses a user-defined type, than this type exists in the db (so that if it doesn't, it gets created). Is there a way to check this?

Clarification:

I have my function definitions in separate files in the form:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(....)
...
END; $$;
```

and my type definitions in the form:

```
CREATE TYPE bar AS (
    ...
);
```

So currently, the only thing I came up with is this: given the knowledge of the name of a type (`bar`), scan the body of the function `foo` with a regex. If `bar` appears somewhere in the function, then check that `bar` exists and create it if it doesn't. However, I have around 50 functions and around 10 types, so if I go and create all the functions, it will take quite some time in scanning.

Comment: What do you mean by 'uses'?  If it is a return or parameter type, the creation throws an error.  If it is used in a cast (for example) in a SQL function, it also throws an error.  However, there are chances that your types can hide in PL/pgSQL functions, causing only a runtime error.  Not to mention dynamically built commands...  Finding these cases is really not simple, you have to parse your function body.

Comment: @dezso thanks for your comment. I have clarified my question.

Comment: I don't get it. If the type is used in the function body in PL/PgSQL it's validated unless you force it not to be by setting `check_function_bodies` off. You can't prove user-defined types aren't referenced by dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`; attempts to do so would fail on the halting problem.

Comment: What's the underlying problem you're trying to solve? Why do you need to do this? Is there some reason you're not just loading all your types then all your functions?

Comment: @CraigRinger at the end of the day this is what I'm going to do. The thing was that I'm writing [rake tasks](https://github.com/ruby/rake) for adding functions to the database. There's a task that adds all functions, but there are also tasks for each separate function. If I add one function, then I must either manually add the types it relies on or just add all types. I wanted to infer the types it depends on as an alternative solution, but it appears to be not worth the effort.

Comment: @CraigRinger consider this: `show check_function_bodies ;
=> on`, but: `CREATE FUNCTION a(p_a integer) RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$ BEGIN PERFORM 'elekdsnj'::enumtype; END; $$;` succeeds while the type `enumtype` does not exist.

Comment: @dezso huh, that's surprising. Thanks for pointing it out. I'm surprised.

Comment: @AlexPopov It's really not worth the effort, as any given type is probably depended on by more than one function, and there's no `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE`.